# Knockoutjs google maps binding with Ajax call

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I have scratched my head on this code with extensive reading and tinkering but can't seem to get myself to apply knockout js on google maps. Let me know if am on the right track. I am rendering a map with some default markers (which is working as intended) then want to update them with points derived from making an ajax call triggered by on change event on the select form. It is possible I am missing on something very basic as this is the first time am using google maps with KO and not quite sure where to separate the  V and the VM

```
my HTML 

    // html form with select option in jinja2
    <form action=""> 
    <select name="categories" onchange="showCategory(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
    {% for c in cat %}
    <option value={{c.id}}>{{c.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    </form>

//a div to display XMLHttpRequest response to make sure am getting that part right
        <div id="demo">
    <h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>
    </div>
 //the map div   
    <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
```

my variables with plus XMLHttpRequest

```
//Declare Map variable and markers array
      var map;
      var marker;
      var markers = [];
      var lat = -1.2886009200028272;
      var lng = 36.822824478149414;

      var features = [
          {
            name: name,
            position: {lat:lat, lng: lng},
            type: 'parking'
          },
          {
            name: name,
            position: {lat:-1.287785734541792, lng: 36.82161211967468},
            type: 'info'
          }
        ];

      // make XMLHttpRequest and update the above variables
      function showCategory(cat_id) {
      var xhttp;    
      if (cat_id == "") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please select a Category";
      return;
      }
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var my_text = this.responseText;
      obj = JSON.parse(my_text);
      raw_lat = obj.Addresses[0].lat
      lat = parseFloat(raw_lat)
      raw_lng = obj.Addresses[0].lng
      lng = parseFloat(raw_lng)
      features = [
          {
            position: {lat:lat, lng: lng},
            type: 'info'
          },
          {
            name: name,
            position: {lat:-1.287785734541792, lng: 36.82161211967468},
            type: 'parking'
          }
        ];

      //check to confirm am getting a response
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;

    }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "/loc/"+cat_id, true);
    xhttp.send();
    };

    //Fetch relevant map icons from Google

      var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
        var icons = {
          parking: {
            icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
          },
          library: {
            icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
          },
          info: {
            icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
          }
        };
```

The map code

```
//create the map and the view model   
      function initMap() {
        var ViewModel = function() {
          var self = this
          self.lat = ko.observable(lat)
          self.lng = ko.observable(lng)
        self.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(self.lat(), self.lng()),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });


       self.updatedfeatures = ko.observableArray(features.slice());
        // Create markers.
        self.updatedfeatures().forEach(function(feature) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: self.map
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        });
      };
      ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
      };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, this turned out to be an overkill. The gist is that the XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous, and the ajax call would set lat and lng values but after the rest of the javascript has run. Of course there is promise in js and deferred updates in KO but i realised there was a much easier way to get the same thing done. I simply moved the XMLHttpRequest function into the map function and used `document.getElementById("myId").addEventListener("change", myFunction);` to make a the ajax request when select value changes, then update the markers. I will not need KO for that, but of course it will come in handy as I do further sorting of the makers after the call

So this is the section of code that I changed

```
//create the map and the view model   
      function initMap() {
        var ViewModel = function() {
          var self = this
          self.lat = ko.observable(lat)
          self.lng = ko.observable(lng)

        self.lng.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        alert("new values are " + newValue);
        });

        self.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(self.lat(), self.lng()),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });


       self.updatedfeatures = ko.observableArray(features);
        // Create markers.
        self.updatedfeatures().forEach(function(feature) {
            self.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: self.map
          });
          markers.push(self.marker);
        });

        document.getElementById("my_cats").addEventListener("change", myFunction);
        function myFunction() {
      var cat_id = document.getElementById("my_cats").value;
      var xhttp;
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var my_text = this.responseText;
      obj = JSON.parse(my_text);
      var raw_lat = obj.Addresses[0].lat;
      lat = parseFloat(raw_lat);
      var raw_lng = obj.Addresses[0].lng;
      lng = parseFloat(raw_lng);
      features = [
          {
            position: {lat:lat, lng: lng},
            type: 'parking'
          },
          {
            name: name,
            position: {lat:-1.287785734541792, lng: 36.82161211967468},
            type: 'parking'
          }
        ];
      features.forEach(function(feature) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: self.map
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        });

    }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "/loc/1", true);
    xhttp.send();
      }


      };
      ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

      };
```